# No square has a decimal expansion ending in 79

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems, decimal-expansion, square-numbers

Show that no square number has a decimal ending in 79. More generally, find all possible two-digit endings for squares.

Let any digit number ending at 79 be represented as
$$a_nx^n+.....+7x+9$$
Plug in 10

$$a_n10^n+.....+79$$

square the expression

$$(a_n10^n+.....+a_2*10^2)^2+2(a_n10^n+....+a_2*10^2*78)+6084\equiv 1 \pmod4$$

so $$(a_n10^n+.....+a_2*10^2)^2+2(a_n10^n+....+a_2*10^2*78)+6083 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$

The first two algebraic parts of the expression must be even and 6083 is odd which implies that the sum is odd which can't be congruent to $0 \pmod4$

Comment: Any odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: any square is congruent to $\{0, 1, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 19, 21, 24\}$ modulo $25$.

Comment: I think I got it. I am going to post the solution